# Not able to tag pages in Facebook page post through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, tagging

I am not able to tag other pages on Facebook Page post through Facebook API. This is working fine when i post on page through login in Facebook.

I had used a no. of requests on graph API Explorer for this with following parameters.

```
graph.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_ID/feed
```

Request# 1

```
message=My message for @[PAGE_ID_TO_BE_TAGGED]
```

Request# 2

```
message=My Message for @[{"PAGE_ID"}:"1":{"PAGE_NAME"}]
```

Request# 3

```
message=PAGE_NAME this is for you.
message_tags={"0": [{"id": "PAGE_ID","name": "PAGE_NAME","type": "page","offset": 0,"length": LENGTH_OF_PAGE_NAME}]}
```

Also tagging seems to be working when i post on my profile.

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed
```

Request Parameters:

```
message=this is new message.
place=PAGE_ID
tags=USER_ID
```

I dont know Where i am missing? Is there any functionality like above for Facebook Pages.

Comment: Tagging within the message text or tagging people as being at a place are two completely different things.

Comment: I here just showed that the functionality is working with profile message but not for Facebook pages. I want to get he similar thing to tag other Facebook Pages within my post.